# NavMesh surface does not work for all orientations

Tags: unity-game-engine, runtime, navmesh

Unity has [video tutorials](https://youtu.be/AeBOj59WWZs) about this where it claims to simply add **NavMeshSurface** component to an object and rotate the object to any orientation to get behaviors like walking on walls, etc.

However, *this does not work for all orientations*. Here is what happens when I try it out for a random surface. Note that I have a script that rebakes the NavMesh for every left mouse button click.

```
if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    surface.BuildNavMesh();
```

[Link to view my video](https://youtu.be/f2lj5nReXbs)

I have a scene in HoloLens2 where walls are generated at runtime and I want a spider to walk on them. So naturally, I want NavMeshes to get generated on walls irrespective of their orientation. Please help.

Add comment

Comment: 196 degrees? Are you sure the navmesh isnt on the other side?

Comment: @BugFinder, I thought the same too. But unfortunately, it is not on the other side. I have shown this in the video.

Comment: I watched the video I dont remember seeing the other side.. they also only demonstrate a 90 degree angle between the walls, the angles on your objects seem a litle weird I'd start with the floor at 0 so its flat, and try recreating what they do

Comment: @BugFinder, that is exactly what I did. I started out with the floor in the correct place and the NavMesh was getting baked correctly. Then I started rotating it and rebaking it. You should try it yourself. In my video, you can see at 0:47 where I go behind the floor and you can see that there is no NavMesh.

Comment: Ive seen instances where it just doesnt show because it draws bad, are you sure this isnt the case?

Comment: @BugFinder, yes I am sure that is not the case. Can you define 'draws bad'? Is there a decent way to check if the NavMesh has been generated? The only way right now is the blue highlight, correct? I don't see any in that case. I have tried this umpteen number of times now. Maybe you can try it out yourself.

Comment: the blue highlight can "not show" a bit like z clashing and no, not now i should have been in bed 2 hours ago but I was on a coding roll